# Is X-GM-MSGID unique across all Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-api, imap, gmail-imap

Is the X-GM-MSGID as defined by the [Gmail IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid) unique across all Gmail 
accounts?

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption.  It is unique enough to guarantee uniqueness across all folders in *your* gmail account.  That's all the documentation guarantees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is not. X-GM-MSGID is not a unique message identifier across gmail accounts. :/

Comment: @Ali Do you have any reference URL for this?